# Repeated properties from same Node when using keys()

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I was trying to get all the properties from the nodes with their labels when:

[image: Query]

As you can see, the first and fifth rows belong to the same node label, but their properties have switched places. They seem to be the same individually, so it's not a case sensitive problem.

Querying with

```
MATCH (N:INCIDENT) RETURN COUNT(N)
```

returns the sum of the *count(N)* value of both rows.

I'm using [keys()](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/functions/list/#functions-keys) to return the properties, the value being a list of the map [the properties are structured as](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/syntax/values/#structural-types). I know maps are not ordered per-se, but this kind of defeats the point.

This is how I create the offending nodes:

[image: Creation]

Is it supposed to work like this? I'd understand the duplicate if the nodes lacked one of the properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since a node can have multiple labels, the following is a safer version of @logisma's second query. It uses the APOC function [apoc.coll.sort](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/) to sort the `labels` **and** `keys` collections to ensure that differing label/key ordering does not affect the results.

```
MATCH (n)
RETURN
  apoc.coll.sort(LABELS(n)) AS labels,
  apoc.coll.sort(KEYS(n)) AS keys,
  COUNT(*);
```

Comment: So I have to rely on APOC it seems, but, any idea about why does this happen? It may help me avoid the problem if it stems from my node creation. Thank you.

Comment: The order in which labels and properties are returned is an implementation detail, and is not documented. Therefore, you should not assume any particular ordering or that it is will be consistent.

Comment: Okay, that really helps. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this query :

```
MATCH (n) 
WITH labels(n) AS labels, keys(n) AS keys
UNWIND keys AS key 
WITH labels, key ORDER BY labels, key
RETURN labels, collect(DISTINCT key) AS keys, count(*)
```

But this query will be slow because you scan all the nodes ...

If you have *APOC*, you can also use the `apoc.coll.sort(coll)` function to sort the `keys()` array :

```
MATCH (n) 
RETURN labels(n) AS labels, apoc.coll.sort(keys(n)) AS keys, count(*)
```

Comment: The first query doesn't quite work right, since it uses 2 [aggregation functions](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.3/cypher/functions/aggregating/#query-functions-aggregating) (`COLLECT` and `COUNT`), and uses `labels` as the grouping key. This means that all the keys for `labels` will be combined together, even if they do not always appear together in all relevant nodes.